# How do I create safe FFI bindings for a library where resources can be invalidated at any time?

Tags: rust, wayland

I'm trying to create a Wayland compositor in Rust. Wayland is a successor to the X11 windowing system. One of the most feature complete libraries for Wayland development is called [wlroots](https://github.com/swaywm/wlroots) and it's written in/for C. I've used it a little in the past, but in C. Unfortunately, it looks like creating safe Rust bindings for it will be difficult.

The author of the now-archived Way-Cooler project attempted to create safe bindings but had [an immensely difficult time and eventually gave up on it](http://way-cooler.org/blog/2019/04/29/rewriting-way-cooler-in-c.html).

The main issue seems to be the fact that Wayland "resources" - stuff like keyboards and monitor connections - can be removed at any time by the user by just unplugging the video cable. Wayland posts a callback when this happens, but memory like this that could just get deleted at any point is obviously not safe and is not allowed by Rust.

I've coded in Rust before but I'm not an expert in memory management or all the tools Rust provides in std/non-std crates to help with this. How can I go about implementing this in hopefully a more elegant/simple manner than the previous effort to do the same thing?

Comment: The blog post shows the route I would go: having weak-pointer-like semantics that get checked for validity and upgraded to references, then pass the reference to the rest of the code. Anything else seems likely to not be memory safe.

Comment: @Shepmaster this still isn't safe; the device could be unplugged while you are borrowing the reference. I think the only safe way is to isolate the possible UB in its own process, which you can kill when you receive the callback.

Comment: @PeterHall I suppose that depends on how the C library is implemented. It could have a queue of messages from the OS and only process them at known points (e.g. the beginning of the event loop, as mentioned in the blog post). If unplugged in the middle, any remaining commands might just go into the aether but not cause memory unsafety.

Comment: @Shepmaster true. This question cannot be properly answered without knowing the detailed implementation of the C library.

Comment: I think your question is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/q/61106587/155423